# How to convert a nonlinear constraints into linear constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints

I met problem, for example:

$\min x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ 
$\operatorname{sub} x_1^2 + 2x_1 + x_2^2 + 4x_2 + x_3^2 + 3x_3 \le 0 $

How to convert such nonlinear constraints into linear constraints?

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The constraint models a spherical region, and thus impossible to represent using linear constraints (draw a circle on paper and then try to describe it using (a finite number) of straight lines...)

Comment: thank you so much